# Insert carriage return at first instance of character in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with hundreds of lines. Each line contain the below information:

```
software.cisco.com , Added by IT, ZZ 6584
```

What I am trying to do is insert carriage return where the first comma is. I'm able to do this with search/replace and using the /n expression. Problem is it inserts carriage return twice leaving me with 3 lines. I am trying to insert carriage return at first comma only and keep rest of line.

Before:

```
software.cisco.com , Added by IT, ZZ 6584
```

After:

```
software.cisco.com
#Added by IT, ZZ 6584
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
^(.*?),\s*
```

Replacement: `$1\n#`.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/aNpply/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```